# AuthN and AuthZ for multi layer node app

Tags: node.js, express, passport.js, restify

I'm building an App using NodeJS targeting the following architecture

- MongoDB
- API layer with restify
- Express Web Server which is serving an Angular SPA

The backend API should consume data from services like facebook or instagram.

So my initial idea was to implement passport in the express layer and forward profile information and tokens to the API (which stores all those information in mongo). Once user is authenticated I thought about using passorts middleware to authenticate each API call.

which information would you pass between frontend app and api layer? And the most important question: Is such an implementation secure? using only the information from the external identity provider?

Comment: Which passport strategy were you thinking of using to authenticate for each API call?

Comment: Thats also a good question, I'm using passport-instagram and passport-facebook in the frontend, both gave me an accesstoken and refreshtoken in conjunction with users profile. That's exactly why I'm not sure if its the right way. I've actuellay nothing more than those information about a user

Comment: For me your question raises more questions. What exactly is your API responsible for? What does the API need to know about the user, if anything? If you're using OAuth on the front end to access Instagram and Facebook why is the API also consuming data from Instagram and Facebook?